# Convert Cordova Camera Captured Image File to File Object to save in Rails Application Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cordova, camera, ionic-framework

I am developing ionic application where I am using Rails Api for backend.
I am uploading file via camera capture plugins cordova-camera and cordova-file. I am getting the file which was stored in android phone cache. I need to upload this file into database along with the form input data. For that I need to convert it to a File Object.

For normal input file upload I have use ng-file-upload where it is retreiving file object where I ma saving in it backend sending as param like this:

```
"image"=>#<ActionController::UploadedStringIO:0xb4c9bae4>
```

And ng-file-upload File object is lookig like this:

```
File {}
lastModified: 1460033422638
lastModifiedDate: Thu Apr 07 2016 18:20:22 GMT+0530 (IST)
name: "images.jpg"
size: 4003
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

I need to save camera captured image as File Object so that I will send this File Object as parameter to rails action to save image in DB along with form input.

I have tried like this but no use in angularjs ionic app:

```
var options = new File();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.name = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.type = "image/jpeg";
var params = new Object();         
params.imageURI = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);         
options.params = params;        
options.chunkedMode = false;
```

Can you please help me out regarding this.